# Is it possible in excel to have data pull from different cells based on a dropbox?

Tags: microsoft-excel

So I am not sure what to look for as far as what it would even be called but i am trying to set up a sheet where it changes multiple cells formulas when you change to a different sequence in a drop box

example sheet 1 a1 would pull from sheet 2 a1 when drop down box a is selected but change when box b is selected to sheet 2 a2

I am not looking for someone to give me the code unless they happen to have it, i just want to know what if its possible and what it is exactly i need to look for either on google or formulas to use

Comment: Both actions are possible, best is Macro. Specify what change you want in Sheet 2 !

Comment: Yes. VLOOKUP() will probably do what you need without the requirement for Macro's

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample plese refer to this formula:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet2!a"&COLUMN(INDIRECT(B1&":"&B1)))
```

[image]